# Change Div to fit bottom portion of website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to put an image at the bottom of my navigation bar and behind my slider but i cannot seem to get it to fit bottom portion of the navigation screen. I used position abs, and relative but it messes up the slider. This is what i have. Can someone help or know of any links that go further into this.

```
This is the code
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CresX/2725/

```
after #sliderbackground edit(suppose to be green, bottom portion of navigation bar)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CresX/2725/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For  #slidy-container use position: absolute; and set bottom,left and right css properties.

```
 #slidy-container {
    width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:55%;
    height:400px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:-200px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
```

}

I have updated the css and available at the following link.

http://jsfiddle.net/w00eevyu/

Comment: the issue is the #sliderbackground(i.e the green box) im trying to move it to the bottom portion of the website under the navigation bar and under the #slider-container. @Rejoy